# Can we have $n^2\mid m^m-1$ for another $n\ge 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, carmichael-function

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016350/n-such-that-n2-mid-varphin-varphin-1-can-n-be-a-prime-numbe/4017424#4017424) but instead of $\varphi(n)$ it ask about a solution , if we replace it by the Carmichael function $\lambda(n)$

I rule out $n=1$ and $n=2$ since in this case we have $\lambda(n)=1$

> Is there $n\ge 3$ besides $$230\ 608\ 999$$ such that $n^2\mid m^m-1$ holds, where $m=\lambda(n)$ and $\lambda(n)$ denotes the Carmichael function ?

As in the other problem, a solution must be odd, squarefree and cyclic. It cannot be an odd prime number. Moreover, I worked out the following :

- The above solution is the only one in the range $3\le n\le 10^9$
- Martin Hopf checked the Carmichael numbers upto $10^{18}$ (since they are cyclic). None gives a solution
- In the case of $2$ prime factors, the larger must be at least $490\ 000$.

If it is too difficult to decide whether there is a further solution, doublechecks and extensions are also welcome.

Comment: I double checked for $n < 10^9$. Results are confirmed. Trivial solutions are $1$ and $2$, the only non-trivial solution is $230 \ 608 \ 999$.

Comment: No more solutions for $n < 10^{10}$.