# Is $n^2\mid \sigma(n)^{\sigma(n)}-1$ possible for $n>1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

Inspired by Martin Hopf I used another number theoretical function for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016350/n-such-that-n2-mid-varphin-varphin-1-can-n-be-a-prime-numbe/4017424#4017424) question.

> If $\sigma(n)$ is the divisor-sum function ($1$ and $n$ are included, $\sigma(1)=1$) , can we have $$n^ 2\mid \sigma(n)^{\sigma(n)}-1$$ for an integer $n>1$ ?

- There is no solution for $n\le 10^9$
- $n$ cannot be a prime power , since for $n=p^k$ we can easily prove $$\sigma(n)^{\sigma(n)}-1 \equiv p\mod p^2$$
- If $n$ is even, $\sigma(n)$ must be odd which is only possible if $n$ is a perfect square or twice a perfect square ($1$ would also be allowed as the perfect square , but $n=2$ gives no solution). In this case, there is no solution below $10^{14}$. This search limit includes also the odd perfect squares.

Comment: I checked with Carmichael numbers below $10^{18}$. However no solutions found.